# React template that came with aspnetboilerplate is giving a lot of "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: reactjs, aspnetboilerplate

Getting stumped. Of course I was hoping that the default react app would work out of the box that was included into aspnet boilerplate. Unfortunately it doesn't run at all and I get a lot of

```
./src/scenes/Tenants/index.tsx
  Line 73:9:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 73:9:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

That's not the only file that has this problem. Every line with '?' has an issue.

The offending block for this file:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
      if (entityDto.id !== 0) {
        this.formRef.current?.setFieldsValue({...this.props.tenantStore.tenantModel,});
      } else {
    return this.formRef.current?.resetFields();
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  delete(input: EntityDto) {
    const self = this;
    confirm({
      title: 'Do you Want to delete these items?',
      onOk() {
        self.props.tenantStore.delete(input);
      },
      onCancel() {},
    });
  }

  handleCreate = async () => {
    this.formRef.current?.validateFields().then(async (values: any) => {
      if (this.state.tenantId === 0) {
        await this.props.tenantStore.create(values);
      } else {
        await this.props.tenantStore.update({ id: this.state.tenantId, ...values });
      }

      await this.getAll();
      this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
      /*eslint no-unused-expressions: ["error", { "allowTernary": true }]*/
      this.formRef.current?.resetFields();
    });
  };
```

Comment: How to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I... I turned to Angular and now struggle with that. The bottom line was that I foolishly thought it would make sense to update the libraries since there were security alerts about the existing packages. Noob mistake, I guess. I never got out of that endless loop of yet another dependency breaking.